# mkDir(s) vs Files.createDirectory(ies)

Tags: java

What is the difference between `file.mkDir()` and `Files.createDirectory(path)`.
Is there any cases which suites better for any of them? Or `Files.createDirectory(path)` is just newer version of `file.mkDir()` (from newer Java version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is described in java docs.

`file.mkDir()`:

> - Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.
> - @return  `true` if and only if the directory was created; `false` otherwise

`Files.createDirectory(path)`:

> - Creates a new directory. The check for the existence of the file and the
>      creation of the directory if it does not exist are a single operation
>      that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might
>      affect the directory. The {@link #createDirectories createDirectories}
>      method should be used where it is required to create all nonexistent
>      parent directories first.
>
>   The {@code attrs} parameter is optional {@link FileAttribute
>      file-attributes} to set atomically when creating the directory. Each
>      attribute is identified by its {@link FileAttribute#name name}. If more
>      than one attribute of the same name is included in the array then all but
>      the last occurrence is ignored.
> - @return  the directory

Comment: Yep, thank you, I saw these JavaDocs.
But since the second one appeared in a later version of Java (and mkDir() is often refers more to an older version of Java - as 6) is there any preferences in the latest one or these are just 2 methods any of which could be used depending on required return type (and will be handled accordingly)?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with fact, that `mkDir()` is older. It works just fine and can be used if there's a need for it's functionality. You just use whatever method's functionality you need to. There are a lot of methods that come from JDK 1.0 and it's totally OK to use them.

Comment: Thank you @htshame!

Comment: I'm still confused by when you would prefer to use one rather than the other. Is there a performance difference between the two or better thread-safety? Thanks!

Comment: The difference seems to come down to error handling and what you want to do with the code. For example, `mkdir` throws an exception only if you don't have permission to create the folders, while `createDirectory` will throw other exceptions, including if a file exists with the same name as the directory you're trying to create.
`mkdir` is also not atomic, so if it fails to create a folder, it might leave behind all the folders it did create up to that point, while `createDirectory` would leave no folders if it failed.